# Configuration missing settings in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core

I  had a problem setting up configuration for an ASP.NET Core 5 website, and my searches came up short of a solution.

Failing code first...

**Program.cs**

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
  var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(...
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
  IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
   var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => {
      config.AddConfiguration(configuration);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(builder => {
        builder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
       webBuilder
        .UseConfiguration(configuration)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
  return host;
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public class Startup
{
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    _configuration = configuration; // <-- configuration was missing settings
  }
...
```

The problem was this: in startup, `configuration` was coming in without the settings that I had provided via files, secrets, etc.

I have intentionally left (in the above code) all of the dead ends I tried. (And lo, they were many...)

My posted solution, however, shows what I actually needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to having all my config show up in Startup turned out to be the call (as seen below) to `webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration` from within the call to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` in Program.cs

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
  var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile(...
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
  IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

  var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
      webBuilder
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => {
          config.AddConfiguration(configuration);
        })
      .UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
  return host;
}
```

Maybe this is obvious to others, but it certainly wasn't obvious to me.

PS - I see that in .NET 6 there will be a new approach [as outlined here](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-1-looking-inside-configurationmanager-in-dotnet-6/). I mention that because this whole exercise of building my own configuration in advance is because I need configuration info in order to configure the website build itself. As described in the above-referenced article, this chicken-egg problem has been addressed in .NET 6.